# Quantum decoherence - continuous software, discrete hardware interpretation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, universe, simulations, decoherence, computer

Assuming the universe to be a computing machine of some form that executes a specific software program. So far we have reverse engineered the software and it is described by the equations of quantum theory. 
  Let's interpret those equations and their probability distributions as just a continuous description of the world and particles are really a paste of matter/energy that spreads according to the distribution. In this model an electron really exists in all points described by the wave function and it's charge is spread around instead of existing in one point.

Let's assume that the actual machine executing this software is limited in the way it represents data. It can only store the current state of a particle an it's charge in whole numbers. In such a simulation when an observation is made (an interaction happens with our particle) in order to perform the computation our machine "rounds" it's state to a whole number (wave function collapse) and computes the result in a similar way to how we have software that describes continuous mathematics and when it gets executed by our current computers it gets subject to floating point "rounding" rules. Even in our world there is nothing in such software description that suggests how floating point arithmetic really works because that is a property of the hardware.

If this model is correct then looking for explanations of decoherence inside the mathematics of quantum theory is obviously futile even if they really are the correct description of the underlying laws. We would need to find a way to study the executing machine witch would follow a completely unrelated set of rules (if any).

Questions:

- could such model be valid under our current understanding of physics or I'm making some obvious layman mistakes?
- if the model holds water have there been any efforts applied for the study of something similar and it's implications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this question is motivated from (or is at least in the same spirit as) [this comic.](http://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/2012-02-29)

There are a number of mistakes you make in asking your question, so I'm going to answer what I believe to be the spirit of your question:

"If we simulate a quantum system (in a computer), are there instances when decoherence can help conserve total memory (of that computer)? And is this evidence that our universe is a simulation?"

The answer to the first question is yes. Eliminating coherence terms between quantum states through decoherence would certainly remove memory.

Now is this evidence that our universe is a simulation? This is much more philosophy than physics, but I do not believe this is much evidence of a simulation. A world without decoherence is mathematically very different than a world with decoherence. I can't even fathom how much of a mess things would be if there was no decoherence!

That being said that is exactly the point of decoherence theory; that this entangled mess of coherences is actually still there, but that it's just extraordinarily hard to measure it - and that this entangled mess "zoomed-out" averages out to zero (creating what we call decoherence).

So either decoherence is a way of saving memory but creates a VERY different world than the "original" it's meant to simulate, or decoherence is explained with normal quantum mechanics interacting with a complex environment and there's no evidence of our universe being useful for a simulation.

Additionally, one more thing that I want to make clear:

You're really fixated on the "computer" part of the simulation, suggesting some aspects of quantum mechanics could be explained by some hidden computer behind the scenes doing calculations. This rubs very close to trying to come up with a "hidden variable theory" of quantum mechanics, which has been ruled out. Read up on how the Bell Inequalities rule out local-hidden variable theories of quantum mechanics.

Comment: Was not aware of the comic but thanks for pointing it out. I'm a software dev who lacks any formal education in quantum psychics so my fixation on the computer part makes sense :). What i gather from your response is that a"simulation" of the system creates a reality that is very different than the original intent (without decoherence) and that anyway coherence is still present in our real world thus ruling out the limited memory computer.

Comment: you mentioned some mistakes i made in my question. Could i ask what those are for my own education?

Comment: I suspect that you were downvoted mostly because it's a little hard to follow your question because of how long it is (also you're not doing yourself any favors having so many spelling mistakes).

But ok let's try to go through all this:
"In this model an electron really exists in all points described by the wave function and it's charge is spread around instead of existing in one point." 
Not true. I would suggest reading more about the details of quantum mechanics. An electron has a fixed charge even if it has a quantum-mechanical wavefunction.

Comment: Continued:

The wavefunction that you're thinking about is the physical location of that thing that has a fixed charge. That physical location is uncertain, and the electron exists in all of the possibilities of that location. But if you ever decided to look at the electron, it would collapse into one of those physical locations and would have it's fixed charge. 

"particles are really a paste of matter/energy that spreads according to the distribution. "  again, not a paste since wavefunction collapse forces it to a particular answer in the paste. It's only a paste when not observed.

Comment: "Even in our world there is nothing in such software description that suggests how floating point arithmetic really works because that is a property of the hardware."  Pretty sure we fundamentally know how rounding works.

Comment: Regarding the electron charge, the statement was related to my proposed software model and not "reality". Even in our current understanding the fact that the electron's charge is not divisible is an empiric fact - it could very well be an artifact of the simulation, could it not? Same logic applies to the particle "paste".

Comment: I know about probabilities and wave-function collapse, i was only trying to reinterpret the same mathematical relations in different terms (energy being actually distributed according to the wave-function instead of probabilities and collapse becoming "rounding error on interaction")

Comment: And of course we know how rounding works. I was trying to say that there is nothing in the source code of a high level programming language that informs about the rounding. It is an artifact of the machine and the floating point standard. We could very well imagine the same program compiled and run on a machine with infinite floating point space that will not perform such rounding.

Comment: Finally i apologize for spelling mistakes. I think by now it's obvious that English is not my primary language.